# Quiero poner texto al lado de un input-Checkbox

Tags: html, css, formularios, input, checkbox

He estado probando en poder acomodar texto, al lado de un checkbox. Pero no logro que este se posicione en donde quiero. Probé con position: absolute; Pero si hago esto y después achico la pantalla se me rompe el diseño. Por lo que estoy en busca de una solución donde quede el checkbox, y el texto al lado, pero sin usar absolute. Después mi idea es posicionar el checkbox  junto con el texto para que quede alineado verticalmente con las otras partes del formulario.

```css
.S-Formulario {
  background-color: #Bc6c25;
  border: #572b05 solid;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5%;
  height: 70%;
  width: 60%;
  border-radius: 2%;
  margin: 5% auto;
}

.Formulario {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Formulario input, select {
  margin:1%;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
}

.Formulario textarea {
  margin: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
}

#checkbox{
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<section class="S-Formulario"><!-- Formulario -->
  <form action="" method="" enctype="" class="Formulario">
    <input type="text" name="" id="Nombre" placeholder="*Ingrese su nombre" required>
    <input type="email" name="" id="Mail" placeholder="*Ingrese su mail" required>
    <select name="" id="Tipo de consulta" required>
      <option value="1" disabled selected>*Tipo de consulta o comentario</option>

      <option value="2">Información productos</option>

      <option value="3">Información de venta</option>

      <option value="4">Comentario</option>

      <option value="5">otro</option>

    </select>
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="*Ingrese su Comentario/Consulta" required></textarea>
    <input type="checkbox" name="opcion" id="checkbox">
    <p class="Text-checkbox">
      Quiero recibir información sobre las novedades de Dernocua
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="enter">
  </form>
</section>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero encerré en un div padre a tus 2 elementos, que son tu input y el texto. Al div padre vamos a llamar a su clase `contenido`:

```
<div class="contenido">
  <p class="Text-checkbox">
    Quiero recibir información sobre las novedades de Dernocua
  </p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="opcion" id="checkbox">
</div>
```

Y esa clase `contenido` vamos a indicar que sean flexible sus elementos de adentro para que se posicionen uno al lado del otro, con la propiedad `display: flex;`:

```
.contenido {
  display: flex;
}
```

Luego justificamos los elementos para que estén posicionados uno en cada lado, dando un espacio en el medio, usando `justify-content: space-between;`:

```
.contenido {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Obteniendo este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora para arreglar el tema de los anchos, vamos a darle un ancho a cada uno, así:

```
.Text-checkbox {
  width: 90%;
}

#checkbox {
  width: 10%;
}
```

Y el resultado final vendría a ser el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código completo:

```css
.S-Formulario {
  background-color: #Bc6c25;
  border: #572b05 solid;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5%;
  height: 70%;
  width: 60%;
  border-radius: 2%;
  margin: 5% auto;
}

.Formulario {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Formulario input, select {
  margin:1%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.Formulario textarea {
  margin: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
}

.contenido {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.Text-checkbox {
  width: 90%;
}

#checkbox {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<section class="S-Formulario"><!-- Formulario -->
  <form action="" method="" enctype="" class="Formulario">
    <input type="text" name="" id="Nombre" placeholder="*Ingrese su nombre" required>
    <input type="email" name="" id="Mail" placeholder="*Ingrese su mail" required>
    <select name="" id="Tipo de consulta" required>
      <option value="1" disabled selected>*Tipo de consulta o comentario</option>
      <option value="2">Información productos</option>
      <option value="3">Información de venta</option>
      <option value="4">Comentario</option>
      <option value="5">otro</option>
    </select>
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="*Ingrese su Comentario/Consulta" required></textarea>
    <div class="contenido">
      <p class="Text-checkbox">
        Quiero recibir información sobre las novedades de Dernocua
      </p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="opcion" id="checkbox">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="enter">
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó!